# Galaxy S I9000 doesn't start

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s, unbricking, odin

I flashed my *Samsung Galaxy S* with 4.1.1 through Odin. But I didn't like it, so I wanted to restore it to Android 2.3 -- and and while restoring it my computer suddenly restarted and my mobile phone turned off.

Now the problem is that when I try to open my mobile it doesn't respond: 
it gives my a little vibrate but the screen gives me nothing. When I try to start it in download or recovery mode it does the same: it just gives me a little vibrate.

I tried to connect it to my PC but nothing happened. When I charge it, it gives me nothing.

I replaced the battery and it did the same.

Is there anything I can do to revive my phone?